# 'await' has no effect on this type of expression, but it does

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use `useRef` to auto focus on the mui `textfield` in the app. However, the `textfield` only apper after I clicked a `button`, so it is not initially mounted when the app is rendered. Therefore, the `inputRef.current` alway return `undefined` to me when I am using the `useEffect` hook, because the `inputRef` is hooked only after the `textfield` is appeared.

So instead I hook my `inputRef.current?.focus()` on the `button`like this:
`<Button onClick={() => {toggleCreateWindow(); useInput.current?.focus();}}>`

But it won't work either, until I put it like an inline async function like this:
`<Button onClick={ async () => { await toggleCreateWindow(); useInput.current?.focus();}}>`

Now it is working properly, but the vscode always remind me `'await' has no effect on this type of expression`

Do anybody know why the async function works? I mean the function should not be asynchronous because it is only a setState & toggle window function: `const toggleCreateWindow = () => {setOpenCreate(!openCreate);};` Also, why the vscode is giving me this warning?

Much appreicated

Comment: Share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's *not* clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `toggleCreateWindow()` returns `undefined`, the warning is correct. You could (maybe even should) write `async () => { toggleCreateWindow(); await undefined; useInput.current?.focus(); }` instead for the same effect. This will make it clear that `await` doesn't actually await the toggling of the window - it's just a hacky way to mess with the timing. (And it's very prone to breaking, btw).

Comment: Consider using the `autofocus` attribute on the input.

Comment: thanks for your answer, very clear explanation